# How can I recover windows 8.1 boot without using my laptop's windows?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1

I have a laptop with windows 8.1. I installed Arch Linux, and through the process, I stupidly formatted /dev/sda1 which is the boot partition. And now I can't boot into windows. I didn't touch the other partitions. When I checked the partition labels there's one named "Recovery" and another named "Restore".

How can I recover the windows 8.1 boot? Can I make a recovery disk from another laptop? Should I borrow a copy of an installer?

I would prefer to use my own machine and not putting out cash.

Comment: Since you were installing Arch Linux you would probably end up formatting the Boot Partition anyway and install Gummiboot or GRUB on it. [See here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide#For_UEFI_motherboards)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Recovery USB on any computer with Windows 8.1 and same bit version.

I assume your Windows 8.1 is 64-bit as most new computers are equipped with UEFI firmware.

If your Windows is 32-bit then you need another computer with Windows 8.1 32-bit.

MY ADVICE - for every installed OS always keep a installation(and recovery) DVD/USB !

---

You could theoretically create a recovery USB on your own computer using a Linux LiveCD but some knowledge is necessary:

1. You need to copy Windows boot folders and files on USB (for UEFI and BIOS booting)
2. You need the recovery "winre.wim" from your "Recovery" partition if still intact.

I think I have to create a web based tutorial on this ;)

and I am putting my copyright notice on this already :))

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you give more details on the second part? I formatted the boot partitions which "contained" the efi boot files for windows so I don't know where to get it. And what do I do after copying it to the usb?